# processing multiple files in pairs in R

Tags: r

I have multiple `.csv` files in a folder. I would like to select every possible pair and make some calculations. Here is an example files names:

```
files <- c("/Users/st/Desktop/Form_Number_1.csv",
           "/Users/st/Desktop/Form_Number_2.csv",
           "/Users/st/Desktop/Form_Number_3.csv",
           "/Users/st/Desktop/Form_Number_4.csv")
```

For each pair, I would like to merge them by `id` and calculate the correlation and store them.

so, manually,

```
dat1 <- read_csv("/Users/st/Desktop/Form_Number_1.csv")
dat2 <- read_csv("/Users/st/Desktop/Form_Number_2.csv")

dat.merge <- merge(dat1, dat2, by = "id")

correlation <- cor(dat.merge$score.x, dat.merge$score.y)
```

How can I do this  at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`combn` is your friend here.

```
alldat <- map(files, read_csv)
combos <- combn(1:length(alldat), 2)
```

This returns a matrix with 2 rows and `length(alldat)` columns, each column containing one unique combination of the numbers `1..length(alldat)`. We next create a function that calculates the correlation coefficient from two sets, and apply it to every column.

```
calc_func <- function(dat1, dat2) {
  dat.merge <- merge(dat1, dat2, by = "id")
  cor(dat.merge$score.x, dat.merge$score.y)
}

results <- apply(combos, 2, \(x) calc_func(alldat[[ x[1] ]],
                                                  alldat[[ x[2] ]]))
```

That said, I am not a fan of this approach. It would be more elegant and efficient to simply extract the score column from each of the data frames and then calculate the correlation coefficients with one call to `cor`:

```
library(tidyverse)
scores <- map(alldat, ~ .x$score) %>% reduce(cbind)
cor(scores)
```